# Ajax just return error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a problem that I couldn't find in any tutorial here until now. I have a code in Web Service and C# that have to send a email with the password for someone that forgot the password. I have a controller in the service side, a JavaScript with ajax code and a html in my application mobile.

Here is the code:

C# Controller:

```
using LuppBusiness.DataLayer.DAL;
using LuppBusiness.DataLayer.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace LuppAppService.Controllers{
    public class ForgotPasswordController : ApiController{

        public HttpResponseMessage GetForgotPassword(string email) {
                //UsuarioDAL usu = new UsuarioDAL();
                //var obj = usu.EmailUsuario(email);
                EnviarEmailTxt("Recuperação de Senha", "teste", email);

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("200")
            };
        }

        public static bool EnviarEmailTxt(string Assunto, string mensagem, string destinatario)
        {
            string sUserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MENSAGEM.USERNAME"];
            string sPassword = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MENSAGEM.PASSWORD"];
            string sBobdy = mensagem;

            MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
            objEmail.To.Add(destinatario);
            objEmail.From = new MailAddress(sUserName.Trim());
            objEmail.Subject = Assunto;
            objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            objEmail.Body = sBobdy;

            string strSmtp = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MENSAGEM.SMTP"];
            int porta = Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MENSAGEM.PORT"]);
            bool ssl = Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MENSAGEM.SSL"]);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(strSmtp, porta /* TLS */);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.EnableSsl = ssl;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sUserName, sPassword, "");
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(objEmail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
function forgotPassword() {
    var enviar = $("#es-mail").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ email: enviar }),
        url: linkServidor + "api/usuario/GetForgotPassword",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            navigator.notification.alert('Enviamos um e-mail para sua conta.', fn_ErroApp(), "LuppApp");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            navigator.notification.alert('Estamos verificando o problema.', fn_ErroApp(), "Ocorreu um problema.");
        }
    });
}
```

And HTML:

```
 <section id="esqueci-senha" style="display:none;">
            <!--<p id="feedback">not logged in</p>-->
            <div class="caixa-dados-login">
                <form>
                    <div class="barra-superior">
                        <img src="images/trave-horizontal.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-dados">

                        <div class="form-user">
                            <label for="mail"><strong> Email: </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" class="email" id="es-mail">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="barra-inferior"><img src="images/trave-horizontal.png" /></div>

                    <div class="btn-entrar">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-enviar-senha" onclick="forgotPassword()">Enviar</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. As an aside, you shouldn't be able to send people their password, because you shouldn't be storing their password as plain text.

Comment: what would be useful information is the response you see in the browser **developer** tools network tab - i.e. exactly what the server is sending back in response to your request

Comment: I am sorry, i just see the problem now. The error is the ajax always fall in the error function, and i can`t take the reason...

Comment: Hello People. I solved my problem. I just changed the ajax, putting the value of variable in the link and deleting the data. that way:
       ' url: linkServidor + "api/usuario/GetForgotPassword/enviar="+enviar,
        contentType: "application/json",'
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you for everyone who tried to help me. I found a way to solve my problem. For whoever has the same issue follow the solution:

type: "GET",
//data: JSON.stringify(enviar),
url: linkServidor + "api/ForgotPassword/GetForgotPassword?enviar=" + enviar,
contentType: "application/json",

I changed this part of the code, taking out the data and putting the variable in the body of the url. I wait that i can help someone. And i am really grateful for everyone who tried help me.